# SPF record for a shared web-hosted domain

Tags: email, dns, shared-hosting, email-validation, spf

From the definition of SPF, SPF only authorizes IP address. For one of our domain name, we have created an SPF record to allow only `A` and `MX` IPs as genuine sender. This domain is hosted in a shared-hosting environment along with many other customers.

In such setup, owners of other domains on same host can spoof my emails easily. Is there any way SPF still work?

*(correct me if my understanding abt SPF is wrong)*

Comment: But the rest of the internet can't, so that's still a good thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they can spoof them but it would be very very unlikly.

If you are concerned about your personal mails that you send out or automatic mails from any system you provide on said host, you might consider signing them cryptographicaly to enable recipients to check if they are genuine.

I think there techniquies implemented in some mailservers to sign mails automaticly AND there is of course DNS signatures but what the status there is is bejond my knowledge.